# Drawer not identifying layout

Tags: java, android, xml, identity, drawer

I have been trying to make a game, an online text-based PVE multiplayer game, but the app won't compile and I cannot figure out why. It keeps saying it cannot identify the layout.

I am using Sketchware, I always do to get a majority of what I need done, then clean it up in Android Studio. If you need more information, I will give what I can.

```
[/storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/603/app/main/res/layout/game.xml:42:
 error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
 'layout' with value '@layout/_drawer_game').,]
```

Comment: It means @layout/_drawer_game not found in your project

Answer (score 0):

/storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/601/app/src/
main/res/layout/main.xml:44: error: Error: No resource
found that matches the given name (at 'layout' with value
'@layout/_drawer_main')., ] Same problem here.
Solution: Copy your "Savefile" (.Sketchware) to your sd Card or whatever, rename it and uninstall Sketchware.Clear all of the apps remaining data (for example with SD Maid) and reinstall an old version of Sketchware

Comment: Can you add information on what you mean by 'old version'?